# Cakephp 2.x Get List of Loaded Models

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am Struck in problem

```
Fatal Error
Error: Class 'AppModel' not found   
File: D:\xampp\htdocs\sevenrocks_inventory\app\Controller\FrontendController.php    
Line: 51

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\fatal_error.ctp
```

I have check $uses variable . it shows

```
\app\Controller\BaseController.php (line 24)
array(
    (int) 0 => 'Customer'
)
```

Controller is

```
class PagesController extends FrontendController
{
    public $uses = "Customer";
    public $layout = "frontend";
    public $ext = '.php';

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow();

    }
}
```

Then i get list of loaded files. But i could not find any Customer.php or AppModel.php.

Comment: The error is occurring in `FrontendController.php`, but you haven't shown any of that code.